# TClientDataSet: Switching from in memory to provider

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, tclientdataset

I have a situation where we would like to work with some data using TClientDataSet, but I don't always want to save it to the database.  There is pretty clear documentation on using the in memory functions, but I can't find anything saying you can convert it to a data provider.  Can I save the data to a data provider after creating creating it in memory by assigning a provider or anything like that?

Comment: The *data provider* would be the database to which you're not wanting to save it. You can save it as a file without updating the database by using the `FileName` property.

Comment: If you don't want to save data, don't call `ApplyUpdates`. I'm assuming the reason you want to use the same client data set is that the structure from the provider, and structure in memory is the same? Is there any reason you can't simply: connect to a provider, let your user work with the data, then ***not*** `ApplyUpdates`?

Comment: Is that the best option Craig?  Now that you point that out, I don't see any problem with it, unless there is a pit fall I'm not thinking about?  Is there anything to be aware of besides "Don't call ApplyUpdates"?  Because in my case, I wouldn't ever actually save it to file using the ClientDataSet either. (Possibly a specified xml format, but that's an issue for another day...)

Comment: @EricG : Have you seen my answer ?